# how to retrieve ajax data for jquery manipulation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to do something really easy I think, but I can't figure out how to do it...

I'm using a simple ajax call to retrieve json data, but I would like to manipulate those data after my ajax answer...

I've tried a lot but I still have no clue how to do it...

As I said, my code is simple :

```
var res;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        res = data;
    }
});
console.log(res);
// do things with res here...
```

I'm pretty sure the answer is simple...

Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous meaning that the only single safe place to manipulate the data received from the server is inside the success callback, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        // do things with data here...
    }
});
```

If you want to use AJAX you have to stop thinking in terms of sequential programming where each line of your code is executed one after the other but you should rather think in terms of asynchronous callbacks. And organize your code to respect this model.

Comment: I think I get the picture. I managed to get close to what I was looking, I guess I need to change the way I think in my code now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the data in your `success` callback function, for example :

```
success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
        // k represents each key and v represents each value here
        console.log(k + '=' + v);
    });
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/gs8XW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In your `success` function, you must convert the received data from a string to an object by parsing it. This way you can use the data.

```
function myFunctionForJsonData(data) {
    // ...
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var dataJson = $.parseJSON(data);
        myFunctionForJsonData(dataJson);
    }
});
```